# Folland 2.57 and 2.58 - question about limits of integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am working through some exercises in Folland’s *Real Analysis* book and I am confused about the set-up for these particular exercises.

[image]

(note that the errata adds a correction to 58, which is that the limits of integration should be $0$ to $\infty$).

I read through some solutions online and I don’t understand why the limits of integration for the integrals of interest are

$$ \int_0^\infty \int_1^\infty e^{-sxy} \sin x dy dx$$

and

$$ \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 e^{-sx} \sin(2xy) dy dx.$$

By the problem statements, I could understand why the bounds for integration with respect to $x$ are $0$ and $\infty$. Where do the limits of integration for $y$ come from, though? Given the problem statements, this is not immediate to me, and I would like to understand why we use those instead of, say, $0$ to $\infty$.

Also, when I apply Fubini’s theorem, don’t I need my limits of integration to be the same for both integrals? Do I need to multiply by a characteristic function whose domain is the region I am actually interested in, or is any general rectangular region o.k.?

Sorry for the “stupid” questions. These are not obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an application of Fubini's theorem and integration by parts:

(a) Notice that $\int^\infty_1 s e^{-sxy}\sin x\,dy=\frac{\sin x}{x}\int^\infty_{sx}e^{-u}\,du$. An application of Fubini's theorem and a litany of tedious integration by parts yields

\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx &=s\int^\infty_0\int^\infty_1 e^{-sxy}\sin x\,dy\,dx\\
&=s\int^\infty_1\int^\infty_0 e^{-sxt}\sin x\,dx\,y
\end{align}
\begin{align}
I&=\int^\infty_0 e^{-sxt}\sin x\,dx =-e^{-sxy}\cos x\Big|^\infty_0-sy\int^\infty_0 e^{-sxy}\cos x\,dx\\
&=1-sy\int^\infty_0e^{-sxy}\cos x\,dx=1-sy\Big(e^{-sxy}\sin x\Big|^\infty_0+sy\int^\infty_0 e^{-sxy}\sin x\,dx\Big)\\
&=1- s^2y^2I
\end{align}
Hence
$$\int^\infty_0 e^{-ss}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = s\int^\infty_1\frac{dy}{1+(sy)^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(s)=\arctan(s^{-1})$$

---

(b) is similar: It easy to check that
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx}\frac{\sin^2x}{x}\,dx=\int^\infty_0\Big(\int^1_0 e^{-sx} \sin 2xy\,dy\Big)dx
\end{align}
Fubini's and integration by parts yields
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx}\frac{\sin^2x}{x}\,dx&= \int^1_0\Big(\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx} \sin 2xy\,dx\Big)dy
\end{align}

\begin{align}
I&=\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx} \sin 2xy\,dx=\frac{1}{2y}-\frac{s}{2y}\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx}\cos 2xy\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2y}-\frac{s^2}{4y^2}\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx}\sin 2xy\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2y}-\frac{s^2}{4y^2}I
\end{align}
Then
$$I=\frac{2y}{4y^2+x^2}$$
Hence
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 e^{-sx}\frac{\sin^2x}{x}\,dx&=\int^1_0\frac{4y}{4y^2+s^2}=\frac{1}{4}\log(1+4/s^2)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! So, regarding the inner integrals with respect to $y$, it is simply just using clever trickery to get what we actually want to compute the integral of?

Comment: @moofasa: In a way yes. Fubini's theorem can be used to make estimation of some integrals much easier by simply changing the order of integration.